# Почему doPost() в сервлете игнорирует if?

Tags: java-ee, jsp, servlet

Учусь работать с сервлетами.
Создал две **JSP** странички:

Первая используется для редактирования объекта:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action='meals?action=edit' name="editMeal">
    // Содержимое формы
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вторая для создания:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Insert</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action='meals?action=insert' name="insertMeal">
    // Содержимое формы
    <button type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

В чём суть. Каждая **JSP** страница отправляет данные в метод `doPost()` сервлета, где извлекается параметр *action* и в блоке `if` выполняется создание или редактирование:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equals("insert")) {
            // логика создания объекта
        }
        if (action.equals("edit")) {
            // логика редактирования объекта
        }
        // логика отправки запроса
    }
```

При работе с дебаггером я обнаружил, что несмотря на то, что action, например, является *edit*, почему-то выполняется логика внутри блока для *insert*. Из-за этого возникает **NullPointerException**, т.к. для создания и редактирования я запрашиваю разные данные. Почему такое происходит?

Comment: "action, например, является edit, почему-то выполняется логика внутри блока для insert." - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor в ходе проверки дебаггером. Я поставил брейкпоинты внутри блока if, который не должен был выполняться, и были остановки на этих брейкпоинтах. Насколько я знаю, такого не должно происходить, если блок пропускается. Ну из-за этого было возникновение NullPointerException при работе с параметрами, которые не передавались (т.к. для edit и insert передаются разные параметры)

Comment: "Почему такое происходит?" - нипочему. Выполняется какой-то другой код. Например, приведенный в вопросе, не был перекомпилирован.

Comment: @Igor у меня автоматическая сборка, но сейчас перекомпилирую вручную. Если не изменится, скину скриншот, почему я пришёл к такому выводу

Comment: @Igor спасибо, действительно автодеплой заглючил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наиболее вероятная причина:

Выполняется какой-то другой код. Например, приведенный в вопросе код, не был перекомпилирован.